# Randomly put 5 balls into 3 boxes, find the probability that all boxes have balls.

Tags: probability

> Randomly put 5 balls into 3 boxes, find the probability that all boxes have balls.

I think it in this way.

If only 1 box has balls, it'll be (5,0,0) case, i.e. 3 cases.

If 2 boxes have balls, it'll be (4,1,0) case or (3,2,0) case, i.e. 12 cases.

If all boxes have balls, it'll be (3,2,0) case or (3,1,1) case, i.e. 6 cases.

Required probability will be 6/(3+12+6)=2/7.

But my answer is wrong. What's wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are balls = apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all cases are equally likely. For instance, the chance that box 1 has five balls is $1/3^5$, but the chance that box 1 has four balls and box 2 has one ball is $5/3^5$ (if the five balls are labeled A,B,C,D and E, the ball in box 2 can be any one of them; hence the chance is five times the chance that box 1 has five balls).

By the way, if all boxes have balls, the possible combinations should be $(2,2,1)$ (*not* $(3,2,0)$) and $(3,1,1)$.